# How can I test Remote mobile device for SMS and USSD messages?

Tags: tools

I have to test my application with some remote numbers (e.g. South African). What I will do is call an API which itself sends certain USSD message on the number. I want to check the behaviour of the mobile. Is any service available for such testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be interested in our mobile testing platform called SIMTEST. It allows you to test both SMS message delivery and USSD code. We use only real SIM cards for testing, placed in physical locations worldwide (including South African Republic).

If you’re interested, get in touch with us and a dedicated Account Manager will get you started with testing and answer any further questions you might have. We have extensive documentation and guides that could help you with your problem.

You can find more information about SIMTEST here: https://www.simtest.it/

If you want to get in touch, you can email us here: [info@simtest.it](http://info@simtest.it)

Comment: I have received a number of flags for this post but I have to say, even though it is self promotion it's done properly (almost perfectly.) the answer clearly addresses the exact needs of the question, doesn't pretend it isn't commercial, and doesn't pretend there's no affiliation. I honestly feel this is an acceptable answer, and will decline flags saying it is spam. (Still I appreciate the volunteers that flag because 99% of self promotion posts are poorly done and their work is invaluable to keeping the community clean!)

Comment: @corsiKa Thank you for the feedback. Since the OP was asking about a testing service and others were mentioned in the thread as well, we thought it was appropriate to suggest ours as a solution.

Comment: that's why i have upvoted the answer to negate the negative mark.

Answer (score 2):

I did such testing with my previous telecom company.

- *Method 1:* Search in google "receive sms online verification" you end
  with number of virtual number websites, select your required country.
- *Method 2:* If you using any specific SMS gateways then use SMPP
  Protocol tool provided by the SMS platform company, it show the
  status when SMS is delivered to customer.
- *Method 3:* Make few friends from that country and tell them to check
  your sent SMS status on their mobile.

Comment: What i need is sort of accessibility of the remote device. I have some third party exposed api which my application call. That APi then send ussd message to the device. I have to currently engage a remote resource who have the device to check the ussd message.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase number in some service (e.g. twilio/nexmo). There you will have access to that number inbox via API provided by that service

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I am based out of India and was working for a US-based client for whom I was building an SMS application. I needed to test sending and receiving SMS to/from a US phone number for the application I was building using the Vonage/Nexmo SMS API.

My problem was: how could I get access to a US sim or US phone number that I could programmatically send SMS to? I have friends in the US but I couldn't ask them to check their phones for test messages.

Google Voice is unfortunately not available in my country, so that was out of the question.

I purchased a Skype US phone number, but I wasn't able to send messages from Skype to my Vonage virtual number. This is because Skype only sends SMS to select carriers in the US such as AT&T and Verizon etc. Vonage (and many other) virtual numbers are not supported. So though I was able to send outbound messages from my app (receiving on the Skype US number), I could not test inbound messages to my virtual number (webhook testing) via Skype.

Finally I found a service that works very well for my needs: [TextMagic](https://www.textmagic.com/) - a web app that lets you send to and receive messages from a real US phone number that you rent. I was able to successfully use this for all my SMS testing needs. I recommend using their free trial to see if it works for you - if you need a US number for testing text messages.

Comment: Good you are atleast able to work with sms. ussd testing seems still a limitation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Textmagic allows USSD, only SMS.